# How to load a PDF file with browser control in VB6.0

Tags: vb6

I have a VB 6.0 application that has an web browser control to load PDF file. I get the "There is a problem with Adobe Acrobat/Reader.  If it is running, please exit and try again.
 Please any one help me to overcome the problem.

Comment: I made a [googe search](https://www.google.se/search?q=There+is+a+problem+with+Adobe+Acrobat%2FReader.+If+it+is+running%2C+please+exit+and+try+again.&aq=f&oq=There+is+a+problem+with+Adobe+Acrobat%2FReader.+If+it+is+running%2C+please+exit+and+try+again.&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.945&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and found [this](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/error-viewing-pdf-browser-acrobat.html). Maybe [it](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/error-viewing-pdf-browser-acrobat.html) could be useful?

Comment: how can I achieve this pragmatical .. do you have any idea about this?

Comment: i have tried like this.. webbrowswer1.Navigate "Test.pdf".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% aware of your current web browser control (you don't say which web browser it regards). `webbrowswer1` is IE I guess?

If I was You I would have tried a really simple solution first (as mentioned in a link I provided you with) before digging too deep:

> **Issue**
>
> When you try to view a PDF in Internet Explorer, you see the error
>   message, "There is a problem With Adobe Acrobat/Reader. Please exit
>   Adobe Acrobat/Reader and try again." When you click OK to the error,
>   the PDF opens outside the browser.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Create a transform and redeploy Acrobat or Adobe Reader.
>
> Start the Adobe Customization wizard 8 or the Adobe Customization
>   wizard 9 depending on the software version you are installing. Open
>   your previously created .mst file. Under Installation Options, select
>   "Installer will decide which product will be the default." Save the
>   transform. Redeploy Acrobat or Adobe Reader.

Source: [Error viewing PDF in browser](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/error-viewing-pdf-browser-acrobat.html)